# Logout issue in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I have a problem in **logout with CI framework**. When I logout & press **backspace** button then it will take me to logged in page.

I need to do refresh manually after logout to destroy session.

Please help me if anybody know.

**Here is Code for Logout:**

```
function logout() {
        //pr($this->session->userdata[$this->section_name]);
        //exit;
        $lng = (isset($this->session->userdata[$this->section_name]['site_lang_code']) && $this->session->userdata[$this->section_name]['site_lang_code'] != "") ? $this->session->userdata[$this->section_name]['site_lang_code'] : 'es';

        if (isset($this->session->userdata[$this->section_name]['social_login']) && $this->session->userdata[$this->section_name]['social_login'] == 1) {
            $this->SocialLogout($this->session->userdata[$this->section_name]['socialgateway']);
        }
        $this->session->unset_userdata($this->section_name);

        redirect(site_url($lng));
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: can you show what you set session on login and what you do on logout?

Comment: @RakeshSharma Add logout code.

Comment: try to print session after unset is session is still there or not

Comment: why you need to remove cache or need header try redirect(site_url($lng), 'refresh');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be something with cache control meaning browser caching. I don't think redirect helps. you should disable this and use CodeIgniters Cache Library if any caching is needed.

Add the following to the pages where users are required to be logged in:

```
//Prevent browsers from using history to browse in the user system.

$this->CI->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
$this->CI->output->set_header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
$this->CI->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

When pressing back in the browser the page will be refreshed.

Comment: Should I add this in constructor of controller ??

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
redirect("controller/");
```

Answer (score 0):

use `redirect()` to go to the main/home page after logout!

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('login');
redirect('mainController/index', 'refresh');
```